# Visualize a XML defined finite state machine

Tags: finite-automata

I want to know tools which can visualize the state transitions in a [Finite state machine](http://ai-depot.com/FiniteStateMachines/FSM-Background.html) defined in XML. It would be helpful if it can generate animations for the transitions

Answer (score 0):

For visualizing try the [ATT Graphviz tools](http://www.graphviz.org/)
You will probably have to convert from the XML to the specific Graphviz language.